# post.order.add event not triggred opencart

Tags: triggers, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-events

Hello I have created one event "**post.order.add**" but it is not triggered. 
in **admin\controller\extension\module\my_api.php**

```
public function install() {
      $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('myapi', 'post.order.add', 'extension/module/my_api/my_call_api');
    }
```

I have created function **my_call_api** in **catalog\controller\extension\module\my_api.php** and I am sending mail.

```
public function my_call_api($order_id)
    {
        $admin_mail = $this->config->get('config_email');

        mail($admin_mail, "Add Order post id - catlog", $order_id);
    }
```

but it will not triggered even and i am not getting any mail. I got order confirmation mail but not this event mail. 
anything wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load **$this->load->model('extension/event');** inside the install method